# Why is there a contradiction in the proof from Dummit's Abstract Algebra page 92?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading this proof from Dummit's Abstract Algebra page 92:

[image]

The last sentence says there is a contradiction because $|H| = 6$. I couldn't understand why an element of order 3, which is e.g. $g^4$ could not be an element of $H$.

Comment: The sentence says that this is a contradiction, since $\lvert H \rvert = 6$ BUT one can easily exhibit $8$ rotations of a tetrahedron of order $3$. So the contradiction is that these $8$ rotations must be in $H$ and thus $H$ would have at least order $8 > 6$.

Comment: Ah I see :D)) I think the words after BUT doesn't count. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|H| =6$, but according to the above argument there are $8$ elements of order $3$ with that are included in $H$, hence $|H|\ge 8$. This is the contradiction.